# keydown me imprime string vacios

Tags: jquery

Tengo un problema al querer validar el valor de un input, ya que necesito que sean puros números los que ingrese el usuario, pero  presiono la primera tecla y me da un string vació, y realmente no se que estoy haciendo mal, si alguien me ayuda se los agradeceré, ya llevo tiempo intentando y no me sale.

```
var amountNumber = $('#amount-number');
    amountNumber.keydown(function(e) {
    var inputNumber = amountNumber.val();
    console.log(inputNumber);
    var exRegNumber = /([0-9])/g;
    if(!(exRegNumber.test(inputNumber))){
        e.preventDefault();
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Respuesta rápida, puedes usar input del tipo numérico. Su valor default es 0.

```js
var amountNumber = $('#amount-number');
    amountNumber.keydown(function(e) {
    var inputNumber = amountNumber.val();
    console.log(inputNumber);
    var exRegNumber = /([0-9])/g;
    if(!(exRegNumber.test(inputNumber))){
        e.preventDefault();
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="amount-number" value="0" min="0"/>
```

Comment: es mas complejo porque da negativos, gracias

Comment: asignale al input el cero como valor minimo

Answer (score 1):

Buenas para estos casos puedes usar la libreria [Mask](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/) que nos ayuda a agregar mascaras a los input y solucionar en los casos de necesitar solo **números** o letras entre otros espero te ayude saludos.

Es muy fácil de usar y como ves le puedes pasar como parámetro EXPRESIONES REGULARES y te da la libertad de restringir al usuario.

**Ejemplo funcional**

```js
$('#amount-number').mask('ZZ',{translation:  {'Z': {pattern: /[0-9\s]/, recursive: true}}});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.13/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>

<input placeholder="Ingresa solo numeros" id="amount-number" type="text">
```

Comment: e.keyCode esta deprecado y en poco tiempo los navegadores no lo van a  reconocer [keyCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) en su lugar se debe usar [code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code), saludos !

Comment: gracias por el dato voy a cambiar la respuesta